# Detecting and Executing, then using conditional in command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently in 1.9 (15w47c), and I have a command block running this command:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~ ~+1 minecraft:barrier 0 tp @p ~ ~ ~-2
```

It works, but the output is `[15:17:55] Failed to execute 'detect' as betterjakers`, so any conditional command blocks around it will not work. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Your statement is confusing. The error indicates the command *isn't* working, which prevents conditional command blocks from activating that relies on that command block. Are you sure the command is working? I've tried it in-game and when it activates, there is no failure error and conditional command blocks function. As well, are you sure your conditional command block is being used properly; that is, the /execute command block you're using is physically *behind* the conditional block?

Comment: "*Unable to execute **as** <yourname>*"? Sounds like a permissions issue. Do you have the privileges to run commands on this server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work because players who aren't op can't place a `minecraft:barrier`.

You could try placing another block and swapping it out for a barrier afterwards, but that would mean sacrificing a block type for this trick and the other block would be visible for a fraction of a second.

If you're attempting this on a more modern Minecraft version, you might want to try using the levitation enchantment instead, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

You could also try using a different block and take advantage of adventure mode by using the data tag that makes blocks unbreakable in adventure mode.